# swiftUI how to disabled a button for 2sec?

Tags: button, swiftui, disable

i have a bug, if i click on button before the animation before the card flip back. i think for me the best it would be to disable the button for 2 sec, but i made some research and didnt find anything!

```
struct CardBack: View {
    var body: some View {

      Image("back_card")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 250)
    }
}  

struct ContentView: View {

   @State var flipped = false

   @State private var cardsFront = ["bigCard1", "bigCard2", "bigCard3", "bigCard4", "bigCard5" ]

   @State private var cardBack = "back_card"

    @State private var disablled = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack {

            Image(flipped ? self.cardsFront.randomElement()! : self.cardBack)
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(width: 250)
              .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: flipped ? 180 : 0 ), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
            }

            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        self.flipped.toggle()
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            self.flipped.toggle()
                        }
                    }

                }) {
                    Image("circle")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                }


                Button(action: {

                }) {
                    Image("plus")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13, Swift 5

You can set the button as disabled initially and then enable it using the same sort of logic I used here.

import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var changeColor = false

var body: some View {
    TextView(changeColor: $changeColor)
}
}

struct TextView: View {
@Binding var changeColor: Bool
var body: some View {

Text("Hello World")
    .foregroundColor(changeColor ? Color.black: Color.red)
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.changeColor.toggle()
        }
    }
}
}
```

You are almost there, you just need to use the .appear tag in your code to do this.